# Create a view on SharePoint that can look into two document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-views

So i want to have two specific document libraries, one including all the  folders and files I need and the other one including files which I dont need on mz daily basis.

I want to have a view on sharepoint that would allow me to look upon both of the document libraries.

@GuikPoint How would I achieve that ? 
Would I still have the problem of being able to see only 5000 items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to have one library, and one to three views.

Option 1: use metadata

- Create a column called Status (or similar) and populate it with some values such as "Active" and "Inactive" that are set as files are uploaded.
- Create three views:

  - AllItems - an unfiltered view
  - ActiveItems - filtered for Status=Active and set to be the default view.
  - InactiveItems - filtered for Status=Inactive.

Option 2: use folders

- Create a folder named Active and store Active documents there
- Create a folder named Inactive and store Inactive documents there
- Just use the folders to filter the content
- Create a view named AllFiles and change the Folders option to ignore folders (will display all files from all folders)

An alternate to Option 2: Store the Active documents in the root of the library and the inactive documents in a folder. Create the AllFiles view the same as the above.

Advantages and disadvantages:

- The folder version supports permissions. You could secure Active and Inactive differently. (Items cannot be secured based on metadata values.)
- Having two folders feels more like working with two libraries.
- The folder version requires moving files to change status.
- The metadata version requires editing a property to change status.
- Only one place to upload files for the metadata version, but you must set the Status property.
- Two locations to upload files for the folder version, but you never have to set a "Status" property for each new document. Its status is set by its location.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put both libraries on a page.  You can edit page then add the two libraries web part.  You can put them right next to each other.

Let me know if you need the steps on how to do this.

Comment: How would I achieve that ? Would I still have the problem of being able to see only 5000 items ? - Ed1995

Comment: Hi, to achieve this you need to first edit the page.  Then "add a webpart".  Once you click that you will see all of the web parts options you can add.  You should immediately see all of the lists and libraries you have in your site contents.  Just select the list/library you would like.  Then repeat on another web part to add another list.  You can then also modify and create views.  

Yes this will still have the 5000 threshold problem.  To fix that you need to index columns then create views filtering by the newly created indexed columns.  You can find plenty of info on that online.